# Recursive convolution of a PDF with itself

Tags: distributions

I was playing around with some simulations and I am trying to understand and produce an analytical solution for the behaviour I see.

I generated $512$ sets of data, each set containing $10000$ data points. All data sets were drawn from a Rayleigh distribution with the same shape parameter $\sigma$. I label each set $X_{i}$, which has elements $X_{i} = \{x_{j},...,x_{M}\}$, where $M = 10000$.

I then take the average of the data sets as 
$$\bar{X}_{N} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i}^{N} X_{i} $$
to be explicit, not the average of the $X_{i}$, but the average of the sets. The resulting average still contains $M = 10000$ points. Plotting the averaged data sets gives the histograms, as follows:

[image]

What we can clearly see is that as more and more data sets are included in the average, the more normally distributed the resultant data set becomes.

This is to be expected, I think, because of the central limit theorem. Now to my question:

I would like to show this mathematically. I know that the sum of random variables is described by the convolution from the parent distribution of those variables.

I imagine the result to be a two parameter distribution, $F(\sigma, N)$, $\sigma$ being the same shape parameter of the Rayleigh distribution. And $N$ the number of averages, or convolution iterations as per
$$F(x)_{N} = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F_{N - 1}(X) f(x - X) \ dX$$
where $f(x)$ is the original distribution of interest (in my case the Rayeligh).

Is it possible to get such a solution?

---

I have been able to calculate the first and iterations of the convolution. For the $N = 1$ case of the above convolution integral.
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} R(X) R(x - X) \ dX = \\ \frac{1}{4 \sigma^{3}}\exp\left(\frac{-x^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}\right) \left( 2 x \sigma + \exp\left(\frac{x^{2}}{4\sigma^{2}}\right) \sqrt{\pi} \left( x^{2} - 2 \sigma^{2} \right) \rm{erf}(x/2 \sigma) \right)$$

Where $R(x)$ is the Rayleigh distribution. Plotting the above gives a reasonable result if I compare it to my data:
[image]

Comment: If you are trying to show that $\sqrt{N}(\bar{X}-\mu)$ has a normal limiting distribution, then using moment generating functions might be an simpler approach.

Comment: .. or, more generally, characteristic functions (/Fourier transforms).

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "get such a solution." An expression for its density function would not be tractable, because the Rayleigh is essentially a chi(2) distribution.  Sums of *squares* of Rayleigh variables are easy to work with, but not sums of the variables themselves.

Comment: @JimB are you Mathematica S.E. JimB? Care to provide an answer? I've not come across this technique.

Comment: @Whuber I have added the first stage of such a calculation to my answer.

Comment: I see neither an answer nor a calculation.  The characteristic function method is not going to help get useful explicit answers: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution for the cf (a polynomial combination of confluent hypergeometric functions).

Comment: @whuber My mistake. My additions are up.

Comment: That's helpful, because it suggests (correctly) that as you continue to perform successive convolutions, the number of terms will increase in proportion to $N.$  You will obtain a sum whose terms themselves become increasingly complicated.  Although that might yield some kind of formula, it's unclear what it could accomplish for any statistical theory or application, which returns us to the issue: what exactly do you mean by "get a solution"?

Comment: @whuber I can't get past the $N = 1$ stage because that is far beyond my pen and paper abilities to solve and Mathematica can' solve it. I wanted a closed form solution, where I have some distribution $F(\sigma, N)$ where I can define the number of convolutions. It occurs to me that this is stupid to wish for as aclosed form solution in this case because the explicit integral would need to be computed for each integer value of $N$. Interestingly a Weibull distribution more or less approximates the behaviour, so works for my simulation purposes. A real solution would have been more satisfying.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "real solution." There are a great many useful ways to specify distributions, including (but not limited to) the CDF, PDF, MGF, CF, and CGF. For analyzing them, various approximations and asymptotic expressions can be quite useful.  Often it's fruitless to insist on obtaining one version (such as the PDF) but some other version can be extremely simple.

Comment: You have a small typo in the last equation:  $\exp{(-x^2/4\sigma^2)}$ should be  $\exp{(x^2/4\sigma^2)}$.  And that gives you the density for the sum rather than the mean of two i.i.d. Rayleigh random variables.  In short, I think you should follow the advice of the two experts.  If your objective is to obtain the limiting distribution, then using characteristic functions is certainly the better way to go.  If you think you need something close to "exact" distribution for say $N=43$, then comparing the distribution of a huge random sample against the limiting distribution might be adequate.

Comment: @JimB Nice spot. Maybe I should ask the technicalities over on MM S.E because I'm not sure how to compute the convolution further than the case I have given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a quick outline determining the limiting distribution of the sample mean of $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ using moment generating functions.

All of the $X_i$ are independent and have the same distribution:  $X_i \sim \text{Rayleigh}(\sigma)$.  We have $\mu=\text{E}(X_i)=\sigma \sqrt{\pi/2}$.  Let

$$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$

We look at the limiting distribution of

$$Z=\sqrt{n}(S_n/n-\mu)$$

using moment generating functions.  The moment generating function of a Rayleigh distribution is

$$M(t)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \sigma  t \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{\sigma  t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+1\right) \exp \left(\frac{\sigma ^2 t^2}{2}\right)+1$$

The moment generating function of $S_n$ is simply $M(t)^n$.  We also know that the moment generating function of $a S_n+b$ (where $a$ and $b$ are known constants) is $e^{b t} M(a t)^n$.  So the moment generating function of $Z=\sqrt{n}(S_n/n-\mu)$ is

$$e^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left(-\sqrt{n}\right) \sigma  t} \left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \sigma  t e^{\frac{\sigma ^2 t^2}{2 n}} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{\sigma  t}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{n}}\right)+1\right)}{\sqrt{n}}+1\right)^n$$

Taking the limit as $n->\infty$ we have

$$e^{\frac{1}{4} (4-\pi) \sigma ^2 t^2}$$

for the moment generating function.  As the moment generating function for a normal distrbution with mean $m$ and variance $v$ is

$$e^{m t+\frac{t^2 v}{2}}$$

we see that our limiting moment generating function represents a normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\frac{1}{2} (4-\pi ) \sigma ^2$.  What this means is that we can use a normal distribution with mean $\sigma \sqrt{\pi/2}$ and variance $\frac{1}{2} (4-\pi ) \sigma ^2/n$ to approximate the distribution of $\bar{X}=S_n/n$.

As a partial check consider $n=10$.  We can generate a bunch of samples and plot the resulting histogram and approximate density (using *Mathematica*)

```
n = 10;
\[Sigma] = 1;
z = RandomVariate[RayleighDistribution[1], {1000000, n}];
z = Mean[#] & /@ z;
Show[Histogram[z, 100, "PDF", Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18] &) /@ {"\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(X\), \(_\)]\)", "Probability density"}],
 Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] \[Sigma], Sqrt[(4 - \[Pi]) \[Sigma]^2/(2 n)]], x],
  {x, 0.4, 3}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image: Histogram and approximate pdf]

Comment: Because the OP is aware of the CLT, it's unnecessary to reproduce the steps in a proof: it suffices to compute the mean and variance of the sum of $n$ iid Rayleigh variables and apply the CLT.  But I doubt that's what the OP was looking for in an answer.

Comment: @whuber I understand. But the OP (in a comment) mentioned "I've not come across this technique." So I gave a few details.

Comment: I'm going to accept @JimB's answer. This has provided me a lot more information to play with. Thanks!

Comment: If the need is to find pdf values for a particular value of $N$ (given that there doesn't appear to be a nice closed-form solution for $N>2$), then are a few ways to do that.  Here are three:  (1) Take a large random sample and obtain a nonparmetric density estimate (`SmoothHistogram` and `SmoothKernelDistribution`).  (2) Use another distribution that matches say the first 3 moments and use that as an approximation.  The `SkewNormal` distribution might be considered (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution).  (3) Use numerical integration (but only useful for small $N$).